# Difference between LinkedList<?> and LinkedList<Object>

Tags: java, linked-list

Is there any difference between `LinkedList< ? >` and `LinkedList< Object >` in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This passes compilation:

```
LinkedList<?> list1 = new LinkedList<String> ();
```

This doesn't:

```
LinkedList<Object> list2 = new LinkedList<String> ();
```

i.e. a `LinkedList<?>` variable can be assigned any `LinkedList<SomeType>`. A `LinkedList<Object>` variable can only be assigned a `LinkedList<Object>` (or a raw `LinkedList`, which is not advised to use).

On the other hand the following `add`:

```
LinkedList<?> list1 = new LinkedList<String> ();
list1.add("x");
```

doesn't pass compilation, while the following does:

```
LinkedList<Object> list2 = new LinkedList<Object> ();
list2.add("x");
```

Comment: Why cannot i add any string in list1?

Comment: I think that main point here is that generics are _invariant_. It was done in order to save generics type safety, otherwise the following code might throw class cast exception: `List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> ln = li; // illegal
ln.add(new Float(3.1415));` So `?` was created for such purposes.

Comment: @karan Because `list1` may be assigned any generic LinkedList (`LinkedList<String>`, `LinkedList<Integer>`, etc...), so the compiler doesn't know which elements can be added to it safely.

Comment: @Eran thanks, it was helpful